# how to return to previous activity from about with a button click?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, dialog, about-box

Im trying to return from the about dialog to the main activity by a button click:

```
public class AboutActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.tiocontas",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putBoolean("FirstTime", false);
    finish();
    //this.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

I've tried both finish() and onBackPressed() with no results, im doing something wrong could someone give me some hints?

Comment: Is your `onClick()` attached to your button in some way that isn't shown, through xml or code not shown? What happens when you click on the button, I assume just nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see in your code, you don't have a button attached to your `onClick()` method. You can do this two ways, in xml or programmatically.

In xml

```
<Button
...
android:onClick="functionName"/>
```

Then in your code, define your function which you named in your xml

```
public void functionName(View v)
{
  // some code
  finish();
}
```

Programmatically, declare your button

```
Button aBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
aBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      // some code
      AboutActivity.this.finish()
    }
});
```

If you have already attached your button to the `onClick()` in some way not shown then you may be finishing your main activity. In which case, describe what happens when you click the button and show your Main Activity

[Docs for OnClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

Comment: Sorry, i thought this would listen for any button and that it would be identified by the onClick(View arg0) variable. Its working now, thank you!

Comment: Nope, it needs to be attached to the listener in some way so the function knows which button to execute that code on, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use multiple `onClick()`s in an `Activity`. Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have already finished; your previous Activity. Remove finish() from MainActivity where you got to your aboutActiivty.

Answer (score 1):

You can call onBackPressed() function on btnclick and then can define the following code
at end in your class:

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

hope this will help you.