# Display results from Database to a new Black Activity

Tags: android, database

i have created a database and run a query which add some elements to results.
I want the button that i have, to respond on click and show the results to a new black activity. I will post my current classes.

Sorry for everything but im very new to android programming. :)

```
 package com.example.pota;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.os.Bundle;

    public class createDatabase extends ListActivity{

private final String DATABASE_NAME = "potaDB";
private final String DATABASE_TABLE = "olaPota";
private final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "favorites";
private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private SQLiteDatabase potaDB=null;;


//Kaleitai otan dimiourgeitai to activiy

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle, Context ctx){


    super.onCreate(icicle);
    ArrayList <String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        //Dhmiourgei ti vasi an den uparxei alliws tin anoigei

        this.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, null);

        //Dhmiourgei ena table sti vasi me ta ekseis paidia 

        potaDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE + "(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, category VARCHAR, info TEXT, difficulty INT);", null); 

        //Vazei eggrafes ston pinaka

        potaDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO" + DATABASE_TABLE + "(name, category, info, difficulty)" + "VALUES ('Screwdriver', 'Pota', 'i klassiki vodka lemoni', 5);");

        //Ena query pou tha mas gurisei ta stoixeia tou pinaka

        Cursor c = potaDB.rawQuery("SELECT *" + "FROM" + DATABASE_TABLE,null);

        //Pernoume ta dedomena tou pinaka pou xreiazomaste

        int name1=c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int category1=c.getColumnIndex("category");
        int info1=c.getColumnIndex("info");
        int difficulty1=c.getColumnIndex("difficulty");





        //Pernei ta dedomena ekei pou deixnei o Cursor
        String name = c.getString(name1);
        String category = c.getString(category1);
        String info = c.getString(info1);
        int difficulty = c.getInt(difficulty1);

        //Prosthetei ta trexontai dedomena sto results
        results.add("Onoma Potou: " + name + "Katigoria Potou: " + category + "Suntagi: "+ info + "Duskolia: " + difficulty);












    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }finally {
            if (potaDB != null)
                potaDB.close();
        }


        }
 }
```

And the Main Activity:

```
 package com.example.pota;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



  }
```

Comment: You need to be specific about your problem. Are you getting the data that you want to send to the other `Activity`? Don't know how to send it? I don't even see a `Button` in there

Comment: that is my problem. i dont how know how to code the button response.
i want to display the "results" in a new black activity, but the android tutorials didn't give me much of a help

i have created a button in the xml form called button1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure which `Activity` you want to use the button in but do something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 Button myBtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
mBtn.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReceivingActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("key", value); //name key whatever you want then value is whatever you are sending 
          startActivity(intent); //this starts the next activity through an intent
      }

    }
```

There are different ways to use `onClick()` but this is probably the most popular but it just depends on what you need. [Here is one of my answers that shows how to do it using xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966838/how-to-return-to-previous-activity-from-about-with-a-button-click/14967290#14967290)

You also need to [Read about Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and understand how to use them and what they are capable of.

To get the data in your other `Activity` you will do something like

```
public void onCreate()
{
    ...
    Intent recIntent = getIntent();
    String variableName = recIntent.getStringExtra("key");
}
```

Comment: cant make this work.
i just want to display the results ArrayList from the first class when the button is clicked.

Comment: Display them where? If you want to display them in a different `Activity` then you need to send the `ArrayList` through an `Intent`. If you want to display them in the same `Activity` then you need a `View` such as an `EditText`. If you tell me exactly what you are trying to do and show me what you have then I can help you

Comment: ok
first of all. In my GUI there is One button called button1.
I want when this button is pressed to display the ArrayList called results from the first class that i have posted to a new blank GUI which contains the ArrayList "results"

the first class as you can see creates a database, adds some stuff, and then runs a simple query which adds the contents in the ArrayList results.

Im terribly sorry for the incovinience but im veeeery noob :/