# Insert data to EditText

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I'm making a simple app which has two buttons and one edittext. When the buttons are clicked the edittext wil display values of my database. I tried this code but it did not work

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v == bnt1) {
    SharedPreferences sharename = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String na = sharename.getString("thename", "null");

    edit.setText(na);

    } else if (v == bnt2) {

    SharedPreferences sharedescribed = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String dess = sharedescribed.getString("thedescribed", "null");

    edit.setText(dess);




}
}
```

Please show me the problems.

Comment: "Did not work" how? It crashed? Exhibited odd behavior? Kicked your dog? Exploded? Did nothing? And what should it have done?

Comment: How did it "not work"? Did you declare the `onClick` in your xml?

Comment: When i click button my app is forced close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you probably don't have a `Button` attached to your `onClick()` method which would result in a `null pointer exception` when you try to reference `v` inside the method. There are different ways of implementing this (programmatically or through xml). With what you show (not overriding the `onClick()` method) it looks like you would want to use the xml way which means you need to declare the function for your `Buttons`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:onClick="onClick"
```

then do the same for btn2. Then `v` will reference whichever `Button` was clicked. You can also do this programmatically but setting an `onClickListener`

```
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      // some code
    }
});
```

But then you have to do the same thing for `btn2` so if you want to reuse the same function for both `Button`s then the first method would be preferred.

[Here is a link to a previous answer of mine convering the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966838/how-to-return-to-previous-activity-from-about-with-a-button-click/14967290#14967290)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
  SharedPreferences sharename = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String na = sharename.getString("thename", "null");
    edit.setText(na);
        }
}

btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
  SharedPreferences sharedescribed = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String dess = sharedescribed.getString("thedescribed", "null");

    edit.setText(dess);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
  SharedPreferences sharename = this.getSharedPreferences("sharename", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String prefName = sharename.getString("thename", 0);
    edit.setText(prefName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Exception is NullPointerException. Please check your share preference not null before call getString() method.